# how to update a field based on existing records in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Environment: SQL Server 2012

I need help with a maintenance query to update the 4 nulls in the following illustration. I also have a [sqlfiddle to look at (edited)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/328c0/28)

In this example, the first SideSort null should be 7.0 because there is an existing SideId of 1 that has a value to use. The second should be 8.0.

The same goes for TopSort, however, if there isn't an existing TopId or SideId just default to 1.

[image]

Comment: have you tried if else? or make a stored procedure to do this?

Comment: there is a small bug in your sqlfiddle, line id 6 have sideid 1, should be2 (searched why a join was not working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can so it this way:

```
update Tracker
set topSort = (select top 1 isnull(topSort, 1) from Tracker T where T.topId = Tracker.topId)
where topSort is null

update Tracker
set sideSort = (select top 1 isnull(sideSort, 1) from Tracker T where T.sideId = Tracker.sideId)
where sideSort is null
```

As there are multiple values for the same `topSort` and `sideSort`, I just return `top 1` in the inner query but you may want to replace it with something else that will return just one record.

Answer (score 1):

if the SideId is the not the **id** of the SideSort record to use, join is done on same SideId.
the update is:

```
update t1 
set t1.sidesort = coalesce(t2.sidesort,1)
FROM Tracker t1
  left join Tracker t2 
           on t2.SideId = t1.sideid
           and t2.SideId is not null
where t1.sidesort is null   

update t1 
set t1.topsort = coalesce(t2.topsort,1)
FROM Tracker t1
  left join Tracker t2 
           on t2.topid = t1.topid
           and t2.topId is not null
where t1.topsort is null
```

Comment: Should t2.sideId = t1.sideId